# What format do i need to post the value for date so that it is accepted in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field for date in rails app but when i send the values as `2013-01-12T05:46:01Z` it displays invalid json string. Also i have tried sending `2012-02-14 05:00:00` but this also displays the same error but when i posted `20120214050000+0000` it accepted the date. so how can i post the value for date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Time.parse(string)`

Or you can add a method to the model that you want to insert the date in

Or you can use chronic gem.

Take a look at this [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field?autoplay=true)